# Unable to connect to webpage with Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, web-server

I've inherited a Windows 2008 R2 server (no snickering and let's stay on topic please).

It's on a closed, flat network.

There's a webserver elsewhere in this closed, flat network.

All the other hosts in this network can go to the webserver and see the landing page.  http://10.242.34.100:8000

EXCEPT the W2K8 box.

On the W2K8 box:

- I've turned off  IE ESC
- Made sure port 8000 is allowed through the Advanced Firewall
- Added http://10.242.34.100:8000 to the trusted sites
- I can indeed ping 10.242.34.100

What am I missing?

Comment: Some thoughts: Check the web server logs to see if any request is making it to the web server and if so what is happening to it. If nothing is making it check proxy settings on the 2008 R2 server.

Comment: ping is not a troubleshooting tool for this. First try to double check TCP connectivity using a TCP traceroute tool (a **TCP** traceroute tool, not just a traceroute tool). It is `tcptraceroute` under Unix, no idea under Windows. Then try HTTP, either by hand with `telnet 10.242.34.100 8000` if you have no other tool, or otherwise `curl` or `wget` in verbose mode. It is not clear what reply your box get, nothing? HTTP error code? timeout?

Comment: ^^^. Yes. 100 times yes. `1.` Use the right tool for the job. Ping tells you that... ICMP works. You already knew that network connectivity wasn't the issue by virtue of the fact that other clients can browse the website. `2.` Always provide specific details on the problem. You've told us that the server can't connect but you haven't told us exactly what that means, what the exact symptoms are, or what if any error messages or HTTP status codes you're getting. All of that information is useful to us.

Comment: When trying to use the browser, this is the error thrown:  Unable to connect

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 10.242.34.100.  telnet 10.242.34.100 8000 just hangs.

Comment: Using a different client, such as telnet is good from a connection standpoint but maybe something that operates at the HTTP layer might help also.  I would try maybe launch a Powershell command prompt and run `Invoke-WebRequest http://10.242.34.100:8000` At the same time run Wireshark, find the stream of the request, see what happens.  If you can't install Wireshark, Google for rawcap.exe, you can use that to obtain a trace easily for analysis elsewhere.  If that's out you can use netsh to create a trace also.

Comment: It's a server 2008 box so Invoke-WebRequest isn't on it.  Are you all sure this ins't a group policy thing with W28K or some setting elsewhere?  After all this OS does come locked down out of the box with regard to web settings and such